# How to build a string with the value of a variable embedded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI, I've got:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#thumbs a").click( function() {
      var BGswitch = $(this).attr("href");
      $("#target").css("background-image", "url(BGswitch)");
      return false;
      });
});
</script>
```

And it's not quite working--when I look at the code, the variable itself (BGswitch) is being put in the background-image slot instead of the value of the variable which is supposed to be the href....
Anyone? Some kind of syntax error or something?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#target").attr("background-image", "url(" + BGswitch + ")");
```

Check [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue)

Answer (score 1):

`"url(BGswitch)"` is literally the string "url(BGswitch)". You need to build the string by concatenation:

```
"url(" + BGswitch + ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
$("#target").css("background-image", "url("+BGswitch+")");
```